# How to add AdMob to a Frozen Bubble like game?

Tags: android, admob

I would like to get some help with integrating AdMob into a game structured like Frozen Bubble. I have made the layout with the adview in itself, and tried to load ad in the FrozenBubble.java (which file is the appropriate for it in my game), but it is crashing with NullPointerException for some reason.

Here is my FrozenBubble like code:

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isRunning = true;
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    restoreGamePrefs();

  AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setTesting(true);
    adview.loadAd(re);
...
```

It is the Admob based code... But it is crashing with NullPointerException.

In the layout I have the GameView and the AdMob View:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
  android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_CODE_HERE"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I don't if it is enough information, but not, then you can find the frozen bubble source here, which my game based on:
[Frozen Bubble Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/frozenbubbleplus/source/browse/trunk/frozenbubbleplus/src/org/jfedor/frozenbubble/FrozenBubble.java)

Please look at it, and help me if you can!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Where is the NPE occurring?

Answer (score 1):

You never called `setContentView` with your layout file. As a result, `AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);` will return null, and `adview.loadAd(re);` will crash.

Attach your layout file to your activity prior to calling `findViewById`.